# Why is this ModelForm not valid

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm new to coding with django, and I'm trying to add comments to my blog app, but I'm having trouble with the validation of this form, it always returns False with form.is_valid(), so the object is never saved

views.py

```
def blog_post_detail_view(request, slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(blog_post=obj)

    initial_data = {
        "blog_post": obj,
    }
    form = CommentModelForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment_obj = form.save(commit=False)
        comment_obj.user = request.user
        comment_obj.save()
        form = CommentModelForm()
    else:
        print('not clean')
    context = {
            "object": obj,
            "comments": comments,
            "form": form,
            }
    template_name = 'blog/detail.html'  
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Comment

class CommentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['content','blog_post']
```

HTML

```
<form method='POST' action='.'> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type='submit'>Send</button>
</form>
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content     = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=1)
    blog_post   = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

Comment: Where you do `print('not clean')`, replace that with `print(form.errors)` and you'll see exactly what's being flagged as invalid

Comment: I'm printing it in the power shell, tried form.errors but it doesn't print anything. Should be this printed in the python shell or something?

Comment: It'll print in the terminal window running the dev server. I'd also recommend replacing the second CommentForm in the `is_valid` with a redirect, even if it's just back to `blog_post_detail_view`.